# Can Class Functions Have Parameters That Are Different Class Objects?

Tags: c++, function, class, object, parameters

Let's say I have 2 classes, player and npc. In the header file for class player, could I have a function that has an npc class object as a parameter?

For instance:

player.h:

```
void somefunc(npc npc1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is allowed, as long as a definition or forward declaration for the type has been encountered yet.  You can also have pointers or references to other types, and even parameters of the same class' type.

```
class A {};

class B {
  public:
    void funcA(A a) {}
    void funcAPtr(A* p) {}
    void funcARef(A& r) {}

    void funcB(B b) {}
};

// ...

A a;
B b;
b.funcA(a);
```

This is actually one of the key tenets of object-oriented programming.

In your case specifically, you would want to have a definition for `npc` first, so it might look something like this:

```
// npc.h
class npc {};

// -----

// player.h
#include "npc.h"

class player {
  public:
    void somefunc(npc npc1);
};
```

Or, if you have function bodies in a `.cpp` file, you can just put a forward declaration in the header, and include `npc.h` in the source file.  This is usually safer, especially in cases where you may encounter circular dependency issues.

```
// npc.h
class npc {};

// -----

// player.h
class npc;

class player {
  public:
    void somefunc(npc npc1);
};

// -----

// player.cpp
#include "player.h"
#include "npc.h"

void player::somefunc(npc npc1) {}
// Note that "npc"'s header must be included before the type is actually used.
// For example, it needs to be included before the function's body, even though a
// forward declaration is enough for the function's prototype to work properly.
```

Comment: would class npc npc1 have to be declared in player.h or could it be declared in main.cpp

Comment: also, would class player and class npc both have to be in the same header for this to work?

Comment: @anarchyistheanswer Edited the answer to clarify.  Basically, as long as the compiler has a definition or declaration for `npc`, you're allowed to have parameters of type `npc`.

Comment: thanks for the hasty reply I'll choose you as best in 2 mins

Comment: @anarchyistheanswer That, or use a forward declaration in the header, and put the actual `#include` in the source file, as long as the compiler doesn't need to know any of `npc`'s internal workings for the function signatures.  Edited the answer again. xD

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's totally possible and one thing I'd like to add is that is generally a good thing to receive the parameter as a pointer to a object of that class since you'll not always want to make a copy of an entire object in memory.

Besides that, you could (and should depending on the case) take the parameter as a pointer to a const object so that the method can access whatever it needs from the object without making a copy of it and without modifying it's members.

Comment: Depends on the situation.  If the object wants to keep its own separate copy of the second object, it can be useful to take the parameter by value.  If it wants to keep track of the original, or just needs to look at or modify it without keeping a distinct copy, it's best to take it by pointer or by reference.  Generally, though, taking it as `const T*` or `const T&` is indeed the best choice, unless it's small enough to fit inside a single register.

Comment: Yes, it totally depends on what you want to do with the object.